# Live video streaming service

Tags: live-streaming, red5, http-live-streaming, wowza, red5pro

I want to create a Live streaming solution where registered user can come and create Live stream video of whatever event they want. I tried to find the solution for that in Google search and found some results to perform this, but I am unable to find  which would fit into my requirements. (I can't try all of them and at the end having nothing as a solution so asking the community which 1 or 2 I should go with).

Based on my search I found that I will need a media server (`wowza`, `red5`, `adobe media server` etc.) which will run on `RTMP` protocol. The mentioned servers apart from red5 are extreamly costly and red5 is open source but doesn't have much support and no documentation. Finally I found `red5Pro` which is build on top of red5, but not sure if that can searve my purpose. However each one is claiming to do live stream.

I installed red5 and was able to live stream on my local machine from one browser window to another, but how my users will be able to do so? Would APIs let me do so, do they have promising APIs?

I also found `nginx with RTMP module` but have no idea from where to start integration.

There are companies who are doing the same thing like twitch.tv, what kind of solution and servers they are using?

Comment: Companies like twitch, who are doing this at massive scale, uasually don't use off the shelf solutions.

Comment: Thanks for comment and down vote, but I too know very well that twitch will not be using any of such solutions.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't down vote. I did vote to close as "too broad" however. I suggest you read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask a single, straight forward, answerable question. Stack over flow is not structured well for conversation, to which your question lends itself.

Comment: Thanks for link :)

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari did you ever found solution for this? I am also in search for this

Comment: Hi @user969068 No, I still didn't get any answer to this.